# Iam permission vs resource permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

In aws an IAm user can be given say read access to an s3 bucket using permissions.  Similarly a policy (permission) can be attached to an s3 bucket to allow certain user access to that s3 bucket.  My question is why there are two ways to do it.  Should you define both?  What if user 1 is allowed to access an s3 folder but IAM policy at resource level allows user 2 access to it.  Who wins in this situation?  What is the order of evaluation?

Answer (score 3):

Typically:

- To grant Amazon S3 access to a specific user, it is best to place the policy on the IAM User (or an IAM Group container IAM Users).
- To grant **public access**, place a **Bucket Policy** on the bucket permitting anonymous access.

Yes, it is possible to grant individual access via a Bucket Policy, but this can become quite messy if multiple users are added this way.

The user will be permitted to access the bucket as long as *either* of these methods are used. However, any `Deny` policy will always override an `Allow` policy from either source.

Comment: So I believe the possible reason to have two ways to control access to S3 or other resource is to solve the anonymous user scenario.